# Flutter : need to use BLE & TextToSpeech even when screen is off

Tags: android, ios, flutter, service, background

I think, I'm lost on my flutter project, I need help ! Even ChatGPT cannot help me :D

I already tested those solutions :

- Flutter_background : KO
- Flutter_background_service : KO
- flutter_background_geolocation : KO
- wakelock : KO

I have 2 other ways not still tested :

- FlutterNativeView
- workmanager

I would really appreciate some help on this subject :)